# Cannot connect to home WiFI - Repeated 'Authentication required'

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, home-directory, authentication

##### Problem Description

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I cannot connect to my home WiFi internet connection. Every time I click on my home's WiFi connection, it asks for the password, and after 20 seconds, it shows the same pop-up window, asking for password again and again. The title of the pop-up window is "Authentication required". After I close that window, the connection is no longer clickable. It is visible, but I cannot click on it to connect to it.

[This is the pop-up window I get!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewluV.png)

---

###### Home WiFi settings:

WiFi 2.4 GHz

Security: WPA2

Encryption: AES

---

###### My laptop:

OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

OS Type: 64-bit

GNOME Version: 42.5

Windowing System: X11

Memory: 8.0 GiB

---

##### Important notes

- I have already tried the solution to disable random MAC addressing by adding the following lines to the bottom of the /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file:

```
[device]

wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

- I can connect to my phone's hot spot WiFi and to other WiFis from other locations (bars, restaurants, etc.).
- I switched the password, just to refresh things, and all the other devices work without issues, but this laptop still doesn't.
- Output of `sudo lshw -c network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: f8:28:19:9c:9c:21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=10.0.1.131 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:140 memory:a4200000-a43fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
       logical name: enp3s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 98:29:a6:39:e0:43
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4504000-a4504fff memory:a4500000-a4503fff
```

Comment: I updated the description with a screenshot of the pop-up window.

Comment: I have several other devices that are connected to that WiFi already. It's properly configured. As I said, my laptop can connect to other WiFi connections, but won't connect that this specific one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work

I manually entered the BSSID of the router and then connect with it as a "hidden network" and it worked!